# Visual Studio Intellisense/Colour Coding Problem

Tags: visual-studio

I believe there's a problem with the intellisense.

I've tried repairing visual studio using the VS installer but it's made no difference.

[image]

The '.Show' should be orange but as you can see it's not. The code also runs with no errors.

------------------------------------------------------------ Edit ----------------------------------------------------------

This is what happens when trying to reset import and export settings:

[image]

Comment: Did you tried  reset the settings  (https://www.technipages.com/visual-studio-reset-all-settings)

Comment: Just tried that, see edits. Got an error.

Comment: MSDN suggests to do a repair of visual studio.

Comment: Have tried that to no avail unfortunatley